# How to put image in masterflow

Tags: android, eclipse

How  can I put an image in master/detail flow. My program is going like this:

```
 addItem(new DummyItem("4", "Slika",
            "http://milos-radic-et4.from.hr/files/2014/10/EM%C5%A0A.jpg"));

 addItem(new DummyItem("5", "E-dnevnik", ""));

 addItem(new DummyItem("6", "Web-stranica", "/"));

 addItem(new DummyItem("7", "Vremenik", ""));
```

I want to add image to

`addItem(new DummyItem("4", "Slika", ""));`

Not a link for image. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Read the image from a URL and convert it to string as below

```
File file = new File("/Users/iqbal/Pictures/wallpapers/water-drop.jpg");

        try {           
            // Reading a Image file from file system
            FileInputStream imageInFile = new FileInputStream(file);
            byte imageData[] = new byte[(int) file.length()];
            imageInFile.read(imageData);

            // Converting Image byte array into Base64 String
            String imageDataString = Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(imageData);
          imageInFile.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Image not found" + e);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("Exception while reading the Image " + ioe);
        }
```

Convert back the string to an image as follows

```
 try {
    // Converting a Base64 String into Image byte array

    byte[] imageByteArray = Base64.decodeBase64(imageDataString);

    // Write a image byte array into file system
    FileOutputStream imageOutFile = new FileOutputStream(
            "/Users/iqbal/Pictures/wallpapers/water-drop-after-convert.jpg");

    imageOutFile.write(imageByteArray);

    imageOutFile.close();

   } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Image not found" + e);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println("Exception while reading the Image " + ioe);
    }
```